# Gmail in latest microsoft outlook: can i have both the ability to snooze emails and sort emails into other accounts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I am more or less forced to use microsoft outlook by my employer, and recently set up the latest version with both my institutional email account (a microsoft exchange account) as well as my gmail and other accounts, using the default / recommended configurations.  I noticed that I couldn't move emails between my gmail and other accounts (in either direction), so I looked up how to correct that and learned that I could [remove and re-add my gmail as an IMAP account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/411831/new-outlook-v-1649-cannot-move-emails-to-shared-em.html), which solved that problem.  However, now I can't "snooze" gmail emails!  This has become essential to my work flow, and i hate to have to choose between the two - is there any way i can set it up to have both the ability to move mails between accounts AND the snooze function?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "set it up to have both"? Is that you want to receive emails in one account?

Comment: @Christy thank you - i've clarified in the post that i would like to have both the ability to move mails between accounts AND the snooze function. right now it seems to me like those are mutually exclusive (bc moving mails ONLY works as IMAP, and snoozing DOESNT work as IMAP)

Answer (score 0):

As i know, Outlook desktop doesn't yet have the snooze option. It's suggested that you could refer to this thread and try to add reminders for your email: [How to snooze an email in the desktop version of Outlook?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/how-to-snooze-an-email-in-the-desktop-version-of-outlook/m-p/1984162).

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'm using the outlook desktop version for Mac and the newest version does have the snooze option.  but if i add gmail as an IMAP account so that i can move emails between that account and my other accounts, the option is greyed out :-(

Comment: If the option is greyed out, then in a sense it should be unusable. I'm afraid you can't do both at the same time.